# Statistical indexes order in an asymmetrical distribution

Tags: statistics, means, descriptive-statistics, median

I was wondering what's the order between mode, median, arithmetic mean, geometric mean and harmonic mean in a distribution with positive skewness and in another with negative skewness. Which are the theorems used to prove their relationship?

Comment: You can have mean, median and mode in any order with positive or negative skewness (in the sense of the sign of the third moment about the mean), but often with positive skewness you will see mode $\le$ median $\le$ mean, and the reverse order with negative skewness.  Assuming all values are positive, you will always have harmonic mean $\le$ geometric mean $\le$ arithmetic mean, but these have no natural relationship to mode or median in general.

Comment: thank you, Henry!